# How to execute batch file from Python so that it could alter environment of the calling process?

Tags: python, windows, shell

On Windows there's a 3<sup>rd</sup> party command line tool I would like to use in my python script. Let's say it's `foobar.exe` located under `C:\Program Files (x86)\foobar`. Foobar comes with an additional batch file `init_env.bat` that will set up the shell environment for `foobar.exe` to run.

I want to write a python script, that will first call `init_env.bat` once and then `foobar.exe` multiple times. However, all mechanisms I know of ([subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), [os.system](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) and backticks) seem to spawn a new process for each execution. Therefore, calling `init_env.bat` is useless, because it does not change the environment of the process in which the python script runs and thus every subsequent call to `foobar.exe` fails, because it's environment is not set up.

Is it possible to call `init_env.bat` from python in a way that allows `init_env.bat` to alter the environment of the calling scripts process?

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to call `init_env.bat` from python in a way that allows
>   `init_env.bat` to alter the environment of the calling scripts
>   process?

Not easily, although, if the `init_env.bat` is really simple, you could attempt to parse it, and make the changes to `os.environ` yourself.

Otherwise it's much easier to spawn it in a sub-shell, followed by a call to `set` to output the new environment variables, and parse the output from that.

The following works for me...

**init_env.bat**

```
@echo off
set FOO=foo
set BAR=bar
```

**foobar.bat**

```
@echo off
echo FOO=%FOO%
echo BAR=%BAR%
```

**main.py**

```
import sys, os, subprocess


INIT_ENV_BAT = 'init_env.bat'
FOOBAR_EXE = 'foobar.bat'


def init_env():
    vars = subprocess.check_output([INIT_ENV_BAT, '&&', 'set'], shell=True)
    for var in vars.splitlines():
        k, _, v = map(str.strip, var.strip().partition('='))
        if k.startswith('?'):
            continue
        os.environ[k] = v


def main():
    init_env()
    subprocess.check_call(FOOBAR_EXE, shell=True)
    subprocess.check_call(FOOBAR_EXE, shell=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

...for which `python main.py` outputs...

```
FOO=foo
BAR=bar
FOO=foo
BAR=bar
```

Note that I'm only using a batch file in place of your `foobar.exe` because I don't have a `.exe` file handy which can confirm the environment variables are set.

If you're using a `.exe` file, you can remove the `shell=True` clause from the lines `subprocess.check_call(FOOBAR_EXE, shell=True)`.

Comment: You should not pass `shell=True` unless it's needed. It's NOT needed here.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Upon testing, it looks like it doesn't matter either way. When executing a batch file it'll spawn a shell even without `shell=True`. `subprocess.check_call(['foo.bat', '>', 'foo.bat'])` will still clobber `foo.bat`, so arguably it's better to make it explicit, so that it's apparent that we need to be careful about the parameters.

Comment: Awesome idea! Thanks. For Python 3 support I needed to add `var = var.decode('cp1252')`

Comment: I had to modify one line to `k, _, v = map(str.strip, var.decode().strip().partition('='))` instead, as I was getting the error: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`